# How to add exception in UAC list so that software runs without asking

Tags: windows-vista, uac

Whenever i run few application it asks for UAC list , i have to press continue to run that software.
Is there any way to add some program which i need on daily basis so that i don't have to press continue every time

Comment: What application is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no exception list for UAC.

A easy way to bypass UAC for certain programs, without disabling UAC, is to use [Elevator](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinzugec/archive/2008/05/16/ignore-uac-for-specific-programs.aspx). It will add the **Elevate Me** option to the context menu of programs:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Elevate me do the same thing as "Run as administrator". Or does it hook to the Secure Desktop & presses that "OK" button?

Comment: +1, Yes this program does eliminate the need to press OK on the secure desktop.
But I had a question, this program allows you to bypass UAC Prompt via using task scheduler. Does Task scheduler allow interactive programs..i.e. one which show a UI to the user?

Comment: Yes task scheduler can run programs interactively.

Comment: You don't really need elevator, you could just create the scheduled task with "run with highest privilege" checked... And instead of using a right click, you could use a shortcut like: schtasks /run /TN "Your Task"

Comment: Both options work, although Elevate makes it rather painless.

Comment: @surfasb and makes UAC useless.

Comment: the referral link is dead

Answer (score 1):

There is a new free tool called [LOGINstall](http://www.loginstall.com) which you can use to create UAC exception lists.

It was designed to install software as a simple user (the admin decides which commands can be executed). However you can install this tool complete on your local system and define your own commands/executables.

> LOGINstall is a tool helping unprivileged users to execute
>   administrative commands which have been predefined by the network
>   administrator. These can be interactive setups or configuration
>   procedures that are started in the user logon script. Even older
>   applications - from the time before Windows 7 - often only can be
>   performed in the administrative context. When starting such an
>   application the unprivileged user has to specify an administrative
>   user name and a password via the User Account Control (UAC).

Answer (score 0):

**Additional information**; To elevate without prompt follow the steps below.

Steps to follow:

1. Click  Start and in the instance search type `Local Security Policy` and as it appears in the search result, press Enter to run it, note: UAC will prompt. So pass the UAC prompt correctly. (Note: You can also press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and when the Run dialog appears type: `secpol.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Now expand the Local Policies tree, and click on the Security Options.
3. On the right-side a list of security settings will appear, search for "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode".
4. Right-click on it and choose Properties a dialog will appear.
5. In the middle of the dialog, you'll see a combo box with the default value = "Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries".
6. Click on that comboBox and choose "Elevate without prompting", click Apply and OK (Note: This does NOT require a PC reboot).
7. Double click on the program to verify if it works, but, trust me this will work.

And please [look at these 7 ways](http://4sysops.com/archives/vista%E2%80%99s-uac-8-ways-how-to-elevate-an-application-to-run-it-with-administrator-rights/) too

I hope this information was helpful...

Comment: Its not an exception. it will run all apps without prompt